# Index trait with &str and lifetimes

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement the `Index` trait for a struct with lifetimes and struggle. I want an internal vector to be indexable on a `&str`. I.e. `myqstr["foo"]`.

Here is what I got:

```
pub struct QString<'a> {
    pub params: Vec<Param<'a>>
}

pub struct Param<'a> {
    pub name: &'a str,
    pub value: &'a str,
}

impl<'a, 'b> ::std::ops::Index<&'b str> for QString<'a> {
    type Output = Param<'a>;
    fn index(&self, index: &'b str) -> &Param<'a> {
        &self.params.iter()
            .rposition(|ref p| p.name == index)
            .map(|pos| self.params[pos])
            .unwrap()
    }
}
```

And the error is the classic.

```
   Compiling qstring v0.1.0 (file:///Users/martin/dev/qstring)
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
   --> src/lib.rs:113:10
    |
113 |           &self.params.iter()
    |  __________^
114 | |             .rposition(|ref p| p.name == index)
115 | |             .map(|pos| self.params[pos])
116 | |             .unwrap()
    | |_____________________^ does not live long enough
117 |       }
    |       - temporary value only lives until here
    |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 112:5
```

I understand `Index` wants me to return a borrowed value of the indexed structure, and I know the lifetime of what I want to return is `'a`, but is that even possible in this instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're taking the reference in the wrong place, you want to take the reference inside your `.map` function.

```
self.params.iter()
    .rposition(|ref p| p.name == index)
    .map(|pos| &self.params[pos])
    .unwrap()
```

because you want a reference to the param that is in the `Vec` itself.

It'd also be easier to do

```
self.params.iter()
    .rev()
    .find(|p| p.name == index)
    .unwrap()
```

Comment: thanks! is rev() zero cost? i mean if i want efficiency?

Comment: Yes, `.rev()` only exists for types that can be explicitly iterated from either end so it's efficient.

Comment: @MartinAlgesten, yes, it's zero-cost. `rev()` is only implemented for `DoubleEndedIterator`s

Comment: @loganfsmyth if I want to change to `type Output = Option<Param<'a>>` to get away from that `unwrap()`?

Comment: The `Index` trait is specifically for returning an item that exists inside of something. Since there is no `Option` inside your struct, there isn't anything you could return that would satisfy that requirement. Generally if you want a non-panicing getter, you'd implement it as a normal function like https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.get